# How can I set start time streaming without removing audio track?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I'm recording browser canvas and send videos chunks to backend e transcoded with `ffmpeg` to build a `.m3u8` file, so I need to set up PTS using the command:

```
ffmpeg -v quiet -loglevel error -i test5.webm -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -r 25 -profile:v baseline -b:v 800k -b:a 48k -f mpegts -strict experimental -mpegts_copyts 1 -filter:v setpts=PTS+50.217/TB -y test5new.ts
```

But, filter setpts just work when I remove audio track of video using "-an":

```
ffmpeg -v quiet -loglevel error -i test5.webm -vcodec libx264 -an -r 25 -profile:v baseline -b:v 800k -b:a 48k -f mpegts -strict experimental -mpegts_copyts 1 -filter:v setpts=PTS+50.217/TB -y test5new.ts
```

How can I set start time streaming without removing audio track?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ffmpeg -v quiet -loglevel error -i test5.webm
       -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -r 25 -profile:v baseline -b:v 800k -b:a 48k
       -strict experimental -mpegts_copyts 1 -output_ts_offset 50.217 -y test5new.ts
```